# Convergence of sum of sequences and product of sequences implies convergence sum of sqares of sequences.

Tags: calculus, limits

Prove or falsify:

If the following limits exist:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n+b_n)$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n\cdot b_n)$$
Then the following limit exists:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}({a_n}^2+{b_n}^2)$$

Solution attempt:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}{{a_n}^2+{b_n}^2}=\lim_{n\to\infty}{{(a_n+b_n)}^2-2a_nb_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}{a_n+b_n}\cdot\lim_{n\to\infty}{a_n+b_n}-2\lim_{n\to\infty}{a_nb_n}$$
So it converges too?

Comment: You need to use the properties of the convergent sequences.

Comment: Your reasoning is correct; you are using that the product of two convergent sequences is convergent, and a constant times a convergent sequence is convergent.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hint: $x^2+y^2 = (x+y)^2-2xy$.